# two very similar for loops with different ouputs

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, variables, range

I have to solve a population problem (animals):

If foxes are present, the daily change in rabbit population (prey) will
be: 0.05*rabbit-0.0002*fox*rabbit. Simulate the hypothetical case that the
fox population does not change and is always 100. What will the rabbit
population be after 10 days if it starts with 1000? Your program should work
with float without rounding, except for the final answer, which is to be
rounded down to an integer.

I have coded different codes with different outputs. And I don't understand, why there are different outputs.

I have tried the following code:

code1 - wrong output

```
day=10
fox=100
rabbit=1000
change_rabbit = 0.05 * rabbit -0.0002*fox*rabbit

for i in range(day):
    rabbit+= change_rabbit
    print(int(rabbit))`
```

code2 - right output

```
day=10
fox=100
rabbit=1000
increase_rabbit=0.05
change_rabbit = increase_rabbit * rabbit -0.0002* fox *rabbit

for i in range(day):
    rabbit+= increase_rabbit * rabbit -0.0002* fox *rabbit
    print(int(rabbit))`
```

Comment: In the first code, `change_rabbit` is calculated based always on the original 1000 rabbits. In the second code, `rabbit += ...` does the calculation based on the up-to-date number of rabbits. The second one is correct.

Comment: In the first one, `change_rabbit` is calculated only once bofore you start iterating, so it's always considering that the `rabbit` popultion is 1000, even though each day it decreases. The second version properly calculates that formula using the previous iteration's (day's) `rabbit` population.

Comment: Just put the `change_rabbit` calculation directly in the for loop so it is recalculated with the new `rabbit` value each time, e.g. `rabbit += 0.05 * rabbit - 0.0002 * fox * rabbit` and remove the `change_rabbit` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first code, you compute `change_rabbit` before entering the loop.
In the line

```
change_rabbit = increase_rabbit * rabbit -0.0002* fox *rabbit
```

you assign the value `4999999` to the variable `change_rabbit` in memory.
Then, every time you call `rabbit+= change_rabbit` in the loop, the `rabbit` variable get increased by the value stored in memory for the variable `change_rabbit`, which is `4999999`.

The second code is what you want to do: you compute the new value for `rabbit` depending on the value `rabbit` had in the previous iteration. You can't use `change_rabbit` directly as it is already computed and won't take into account the change in the `rabbit` variable. You could define a function for `change_rabbit`, taking the current number of rabbits as a parameter if you want to avoid code repetition.